# jboss-negotiation-toolkit 'secured' test not working (SPNEGO authentication fails)

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, jboss7.x, windows-authentication, spnego

I've posted the same question on the JBoss PicketBox forum a few days ago but haven't received any replies yet (https://community.jboss.org/thread/220959). So I thought maybe I'll try StackOverflow to reach a larger audience.

I have been trying to get the jboss-negotiation-toolkit to work for a few weeks now and I think I've tried everything that other people have run into. I'm now stuck at the point where I can't get the 'secured' version of the servlet working. The 'security domain test' as well as the 'basic negotation' tests work fine but JBoss continues to throw 'LoginException's when trying to open the secured link. I'm pretty certain that it's got something to do with some AD/Kerberos setup but I haven't been able to make any more progress.

```
11:49:43,514 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Continuation Required.
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.login(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:174) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    ...
```

**Has anyone run into the same issue or does anyone have any suggestions of where the problem could be?** Sorry for the huge post but below are all the details of the setup and how I've configured things this far, trying to provide as much detail as possible.

Here's our setup:

- Windows 2008 AD  (QAAD)

  - DNS name: qaad.dev.company.com
  - Domain: QUALITY (QUALITY.COMPANY.COM)
- CentOS 6.2 running JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final  (BARDEV1)

  - Deployed: jboss-negotiation-toolkit-2.2.2.Final
  - DNS name: bardev1.dev.company.com
- Test clients are WinXP and Win7 joined to QUALITY domain

BARDEV1 is currently joined to the quality domain (***is this necessary or should it work without being joined to the domain?***).

**JBoss SPNEGO config** is:

```
<security-domain name="qaad_kerberos" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
            <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
            <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM"/>
            <module-option name="keyTab" value="/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.final/standalone/configuration/bardev1_qaad_rc4.keytab"/>
            <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
            <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
            <module-option name="refreshKrb5Config" value="false"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
<security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
            <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="qaad_kerberos"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

**/etc/krb5.conf** is set to:

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
default_realm = QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac

[realms]
QUALITY.COMPANY.COM = {
  kdc = qaad.dev.company.com
  admin_server = qaad.dev.company.com
  default_domain = quality.company.com
}

[domain_realm]
.quality.company.com = QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
quality.company.com = QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
```

QAAD box has 'computer' account for 'bardev1'. This account has delegation set to 'Trust this computer for delgation to any service (Kerberos only)'.
keytab was generated on QAAD box and SPN was set with the following commands:

- setspn -S HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM bardev1
- ktpass /out bardev1_qaad_rc4.keytab /princ HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM /mapuser quality\administrator -crypto RC4-HMAC-NT -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /pass * /kvno 0

  - (Note: had to set /kvno 0 because otherwise I got: KrbException: Specified version of key is not available (44))
- setspn -L bardev1

  - output:
    Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=bardev1,CN=Computers,DC=quality,DC=company,DC=com:
        HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
        HOST/bardev1.dev.company.com
        HOST/BARDEV1
- setspn -L administrator

  - output:
    Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=quality,DC=company,DC=com:
        HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com

Used the 'Administrator' account for initial tests so I wouldn't have to deal with new user accounts. That account has delegation set to **'Trust this computer for delgation to any service (Kerberos only)'** and has no other account options set like 'use kerberos DES encryption...', 'account supports AES 128/256...' or 'do not require kerberos preauth'. ***Are any of them needed?***

From the client machines, in order to get the browsers to use the logged in user's credentials, I have to set the URL to:

- http:// bardev1:8080/jboss-negotiation-toolkit-2.2.2.Final

If I put it as:

- http:// bardev1.dev.company.com:8080/jboss-negotiation-toolkit-2.2.2.Final

then I get the username and password pop up.

I did try to run the setspn and ktpass with 'HTTP/bardev1@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM' with the same results, i.e. basic and domain tests work, secured doesn't.

**Output from 'SecurityDomainTest':**

*JBoss log:*

```
      12:01:33,229 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.final/standalone/configuration/bardev1_qaad_rc4_domain.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
      12:01:33,238 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) principal's key obtained from the keytab
      12:01:33,241 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Acquire TGT using AS Exchange
      12:01:33,259 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) principal is HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
      12:01:33,269 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: 30 89 05 17 EB 07 89 AE   06 E2 B1 5D 58 B6 6E A4  0..........]X.n.
      12:01:33,273 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:01:33,276 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Added server's keyKerberos Principal HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COMKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
      12:01:33,283 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) 0000: 30 89 05 17 EB 07 89 AE   06 E2 B1 5D 58 B6 6E A4  0..........]X.n.
      12:01:33,285 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:01:33,285 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:01:33,286 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal  HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM to Subject
      12:01:33,288 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Commit Succeeded
      12:01:33,290 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:01:33,295 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
      12:01:33,296 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
```

*Browser:*

```
      Negotiation Toolkit
      Security Domain Test
      Testing security-domain 'qaad_kerberos'

      Authenticated
      Subject:
      Principal: HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
      Private Credential: Ticket (hex) =
      0000: 61 82 04 A6 30 82 04 A2 A0 03 02 01 05 A1 16 1B a...0...........
      0010: 14 51 55 41 4C 49 54 59 2E 53 59 4D 50 48 4F 4E .QUALITY.COMPANY
      0020: 4F 2E 43 4F 4D A2 29 30 27 A0 03 02 01 02 A1 20 O.COM.)0'......
      0030: 30 1E 1B 06 6B 72 62 74 67 74 1B 14 51 55 41 4C 0...krbtgt..QUAL
      ...
      04A0: 1C 85 74 1A 9B EF B9 EE D2 A8 ..t.......

      Client Principal = HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
      Server Principal = krbtgt/QUALITY.COMPANY.COM@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
      Session Key = EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
      0000: 67 2B 5A 9B FE 97 00 2B 68 0B D2 0F 35 FA D1 CB g+Z....+h...5...

      Forwardable Ticket true
      Forwarded Ticket false
      Proxiable Ticket false
      Proxy Ticket false
      Postdated Ticket false
      Renewable Ticket false
      Initial Ticket false
      Auth Time = Tue Feb 05 12:01:33 CST 2013
      Start Time = Tue Feb 05 12:01:33 CST 2013
      End Time = Tue Feb 05 22:01:33 CST 2013
      Renew Till = null
      Client Addresses Null
      Private Credential: Kerberos Principal HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COMKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
      0000: 30 89 05 17 EB 07 89 AE 06 E2 B1 5D 58 B6 6E A4 0..........]X.n.
```

**Output from 'Basic Negotiation':**

*JBoss log:*

```
      12:48:01,226 INFO  [org.jboss.security.negotiation.toolkit.BasicNegotiationServlet] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) No Authorization Header, sending 401
      12:48:01,243 INFO  [org.jboss.security.negotiation.toolkit.BasicNegotiationServlet] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Authorization header received - decoding token.
```

*Browser:*

```
      Negotiation Toolkit
      Basic Negotiation
      WWW-Authenticate - Negotiate YIILwgYGKwYBBQUCoIILtjCCC7KgJDAiBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSq ... i4=

      NegTokenInit
      Message Oid - SPNEGO
      Mech Types - {Kerberos V5 Legacy} {Kerberos V5} {NTLM}
      Req Flags -
      Mech Token -YIILgAYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBuggtvMIILa6A ... Gi4=
      Mech List Mic -
```

**Output from 'Secured':**

*JBoss log:*

```
      12:51:52,877 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.final/standalone/configuration/bardev1_qaad_rc4_domain.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
      12:51:52,894 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) principal's key obtained from the keytab
      12:51:52,895 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Acquire TGT using AS Exchange
      12:51:52,929 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) principal is HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
      12:51:52,933 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: 30 89 05 17 EB 07 89 AE   06 E2 B1 5D 58 B6 6E A4  0..........]X.n.
      12:51:52,937 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:52,939 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Added server's keyKerberos Principal HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COMKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
      12:51:52,944 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) 0000: 30 89 05 17 EB 07 89 AE   06 E2 B1 5D 58 B6 6E A4  0..........]X.n.
      12:51:52,945 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:52,946 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:52,947 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal  HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM to Subject
      12:51:52,949 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Commit Succeeded
      12:51:52,950 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:52,950 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
      12:51:52,952 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
      12:51:52,953 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Continuation Required.
                at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.login(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:174) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
                at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
                at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
                at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
                at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator.authenticate(NegotiationAuthenticator.java:187) [jboss-negotiation-common-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:455) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]


      12:51:52,985 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.final/standalone/configuration/bardev1_qaad_rc4_domain.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
      12:51:52,989 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) principal's key obtained from the keytab
      12:51:52,990 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Acquire TGT using AS Exchange
      12:51:53,015 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) principal is HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM
      12:51:53,058 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: 30 89 05 17 EB 07 89 AE   06 E2 B1 5D 58 B6 6E A4  0..........]X.n.
      12:51:53,060 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:53,061 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Added server's keyKerberos Principal HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COMKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
      12:51:53,063 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) 0000: 30 89 05 17 EB 07 89 AE   06 E2 B1 5D 58 B6 6E A4  0..........]X.n.
      12:51:53,065 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:53,065 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:53,066 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal  HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM to Subject
      12:51:53,068 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1) Commit Succeeded
      12:51:53,068 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)
      12:51:53,081 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
      12:51:53,082 INFO  [stdout] (http-bardev1.dev.company.com-10.10.5.232-8080-1)          [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
```

*Browser:*

```
      HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied
```

### Additional tests/setups performed

I've also tried to run the jboss instance on the QAAD Windows server itself, updated the setspn and ktpass commands but with the same results, the 'secured' test fails with the LoginException.

I've also tried to use a different AD server (COLLAB, running on a Windows 2003 AD server) but again with the same results.

So I'm pretty sure it's some setup/config/environment issue but I just can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Update: we eventually gave up on this solution as we just couldn't make it work. We ended up writing a custom JBoss login module (and Tomcat valve) to take care of the SSO login using a SAML IDP server that the client had but unfortunately it didn't fully comply with the SAML spec and the 'service provider' - 'identity provider' setup that JBoss (PicketLink) provides didn't work out of the box.

It's not ideal but it did the trick for the client and they are happy with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite late.

I ran into the same issue and figured out that we need to modify the web.xml of jboss-negotiation-toolkit little bit.

Modify the security-constraint and login-config of web.xml to look like this:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Restricted</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/Secured/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
<auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
<realm-name>SPNEGO</realm-name>
<form-login-config>
  <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
  <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>    
</login-config>
<security-role>
  <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

then modify the jboss spnego config in standalone.xml to look like this

```
<security-domain name="qaad_kerberos" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/bardev1.dev.company.com@QUALITY.COMPANY.COM"/>
        <module-option name="keyTab" value="/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.final/standalone/configuration/bardev1_qaad_rc4.keytab"/>
        <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="refreshKrb5Config" value="false"/>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
</security-domain>
<security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="qaad_kerberos"/>
    </login-module>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.negotiation.AdvancedLdapLoginModule" flag="requisite">
        <module-option name="bindAuthentication" value="GSSAPI"/>
        <module-option name="jaasSecurityDomain" value="qaad_kerberos"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://your kdc's hostname:389"/>
        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM"/>
        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
        <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
        <module-option name="recurseRoles" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPassword" value="false"/>
        <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
</security-domain>
```